# Sum rows based on criteria in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm stuck with a problem,

I have two sets of data like below:

[image]

How can I find if the sums of column "a" based on ID in Table 1 are equal to column "b" based on ID?
I'm assuming i need a Sumif and Index Match but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: how about `=SUMIF()=SUMIF()`

Answer (score 0):

With the ID's on the right,

```
=SUM(A3,IFERROR(INDIRECT("$D"&MATCH(B3,$E:$E,0)),0))
```

Where A3 is your table 1 "a" value, $D is the column with table 2 "b" values, B3 is the cell with table 1 ID value, and $E:$E is the column with table 2 ID values.

If your ID's were on the left, then VLOOKUP would work with something like:

```
=SUM(B3,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$D$3:$E$5,2,FALSE),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

**How it works:**

1. Write this Array formula in Cell `C3`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill it down.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$2:C2, $B$3:$B$9), 0)),"")}
   ```
2. In Cell `D3` enter this Formula & fill it down.

`=IF(SUMIF(B3:B9,C3,A3:A9)=0,"",SUMIF(B3:B9,C3,A3:A9))`

[image]

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

You can get from Table 1 to Table 2 with a few clicks using a pivot table.  That's a handy built-in wizard that makes it very simple to summarize data in different ways, and it doesn't require any brain power figuring out complex formulas from scratch.  I use LibreOffice Calc, so the user interface is slightly different, but you can easily transfer this to Excel.

Highlight Table 1 and select Insert Pivot Table from the menu.  You will get a wizard that looks more or less like this:

[image]

The data columns will be identified in a box of Available Fields.  Drag ID to the Row fields box, and your `a` to the Data Fields box (I think that box is labeled differently in Excel, but it's the same box).  In LO Calc, the aggregation function defaults to Sum.  In Excel, it may default to Count, if I remember right.  If so, double click on it and select Sum from the choices.

There are some customizing options if you want them, like choosing whether to include row and column totals, and where to stick the pivot table.  When you're done with the selections, you will get a result like this:

[image]

It takes just a few seconds, and no brain cells were harmed in creating this solution.  :-)